# How to synchronize audio and video using ffmpeg libraries?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, synchronization, pts

Stuck writing a very basic media player in C, using SDL and ffmpeg libraries. Initially, followed the theory in [this](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg) page to get an idea about the entire program and the usage of libraries. After coding from scratch, thanks to that tutorial and many other resources,  finally I made my code work, using the latest libraries of ffmpeg and SDL (2.0). But my code lacks a proper synchronization mechanism (actually it lacks a sync mechanism !).

I still don't have a clear idea on how to synchronize the audio and video together as the theory provided in the link is only *very partially* correct (atleast when it comes to using the latest dev libraries).
For example, a sentence in [this](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial05.html) page is as follows :

> However, ffmpeg reorders the packets so that the DTS of the packet being processed by avcodec_decode_video() will always be the same as the PTS of the frame it returns.

I am using *avcodec_decode_video2()* and the DTS of the packet is definitely not the same as pts of the frame it decodes (in general).

I read [this](http://downloads.bbc.co.uk/rd/pubs/reports/1996-02.pdf) very informative BBC report and it makes complete sense. I have a clear idea about PTS and DTS. But the PTS and DTS values that ffmpeg is using for packets and decoded frames is confusing. I wish there were some documentation on that aspect.

Can someone explain the steps to synchronize audio and video ? I only need the steps. I am quite comfortable implementing them. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks !

PS : Here's a screenshot of what I am talking about :

[image]

The huge negative value is, I assume AV_NOPTS_VALUE.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a direct answer, but is a lot of useful information for the above problem. After going through more information and coding a little, the following are my observations :

I provided a `.mpg` file as input and these are my observations :

BBC RD 1996/3 in it's very informative report says :

> To enable backward prediction from a future frame, the coder re-orders the pictures from
>   natural display order to ‘transmission’ (or ‘bitstream’) order so that the B-picture is transmitted after the past
>   and future pictures which it references. (See Fig. 14).
>   This introduces a delay which depends upon the
>   number of consecutive B-pictures.

- The provided input file had it's first few video frames as follows : (in their natural display order)

  `I0 B0 B1 P0 B2 B3 P1 B4 B5 P2 B6 B7 P3 B8 B9 I1` ...
- But the encoder (during the process of encoding, at some time in the past when the file was encoded) puts the packets in the video stream as : (this is to enable decoding of `P` and `B` frames)

  `I0 P0 B0 B1 P1 B2 B3 P2 B4 B5 P3 B6 B7 I1 B8 B9` ...
- Now, when  `av_read_frame()` reads packets from the video stream, they are obtained in the same above order :

  `I0 P0 B0 B1 P1 B2 B3 P2 B4 B5 P3 B6 B7 I1 B8 B9` ...
- This is what `avcodec_decode_video2()` does (or atleast is doing in this case) :

  *Input* `I0` `(pts_I0, dts_I0)` ----->  `DECODER` ----> *No Output Frame*
  *Input* `P0` `(pts_P0, dts_P0)` ----->  `DECODER` ----> *Output* `I0` `(pts_I0, dts_P0)`
  *Input* `B0` `(pts_B0, dts_B0)` ----->  `DECODER` ----> *Output* `B0` `(pts_B0, dts_B0)`
  *Input* `B1` `(pts_B1, dts_B1)` ----->  `DECODER` ----> *Output* `B1` `(pts_B1, dts_B1)`
  *Input* `P1` `(pts_P1, dts_P1)` ----->  `DECODER` ----> *Output* `P0` `(pts_P0, dts_P1)`
  *Input* `B2` `(pts_B2, dts_B2)` ----->  `DECODER` ----> *Output* `B2` `(pts_B2, dts_B2)`
  *Input* `B3` `(pts_B3, dts_B3)` ----->  `DECODER` ----> *Output* `B3` `(pts_B3, dts_B3)`
  *Input* `P2` `(pts_P2, dts_P2)` ----->  `DECODER` ----> *Output* `P1` `(pts_P1, dts_P2)`
  *Input* `B4` `(pts_B4, dts_B4)` ----->  `DECODER` ----> *Output* `B4` `(pts_B4, dts_B4)`
  *Input* `B5` `(pts_B5, dts_B5)` ----->  `DECODER` ----> *Output* `B5` `(pts_B5, dts_B5)`
  *Input* `P3` `(pts_P3, dts_P3)` ----->  `DECODER` ----> *Output* `P2` `(pts_P2, dts_P3)`
  *Input* `B6` `(pts_B6, dts_B6)` ----->  `DECODER` ----> *Output* `B6` `(pts_B6, dts_B6)`
  *Input* `B7` `(pts_B7, dts_B7)` ----->  `DECODER` ----> *Output* `B7` `(pts_B7, dts_B7)`
  *Input* `I1` `(pts_I1, dts_I1)` ----->  `DECODER` ----> *Output* `P3` `(pts_P3, dts_I1)`
  *Input* `B8` `(pts_B8, dts_B8)` ----->  `DECODER` ----> *Output* `B8` `(pts_B8, dts_B8)`
  *Input* `B9` `(pts_B9, dts_B9)` ----->  `DECODER` ----> *Output* `B9` `(pts_B9, dts_B9)`

  ```
    Next Input Packet ---------> DECODER ---------->  Next Output Frame
  ```

  ```
   (pts_PKT, dts_PKT)                                I1 (pts_I1, dts_PKT)
  ```

I think you can now notice that, at every step of decoding, the decoder *already has* the *other frames* (either past frames or future frames of the natural display order) to successfully decode the input packet. The decoder outputs frames in the natural display order. Also as far as I observed, usually the *pts* for access units (packets) containing I or P frames is AV_NOPTS_VALUE.

PS : I do not know ASCII art ! Sorry if the illustration is not too good. Hope it helped others.
Now after knowing this, I guess it helps in understanding pts and dts much better.
[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044335/keyframe-is-not-a-keyframe-av-pkt-flag-key-does-not-decode-to-av-picture-type-i) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96107/can-the-ffmpeg-av-libs-return-an-accurate-pts) are the other ones which I found useful.